# Quickly view a large number of html files in a directory

Tags: file-management, web-browser, file-preview

I have more than 1000 html files in a directory which I want to view. Is there a way to do this like Opening a Navigation Bar to the side (like in many text editors) where I can just keep pressing down key to view html next file on fly? Any other method is also welcome.

**Edit:**

HTML files are static without any CSS, scripts or other files.

Comment: Are they static HTML, or dynamic with JS?

Comment: They are static HTML. Also No CSS file

Comment: I wonder if writing a script to combine the files into one would help you. Or even strip out the content you want to see and put it into a DB or Excel file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any existing software that can do that however I was able to quickly build an application for you. If you are willing to use it of course.
The application will load all your HTML files and you should be able to view them by selecting 1 and then navigate by clicking the up arrow and down arrow.
It also supports CSS and some basic JS if you ever decide to add that.

Let me know if you have any problems or need any further assistance.

I have provided instructions on how to use below.
The download link is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ydvMvIRT4sagyKFJd-VbIrzX9YOnxKWy) and can also be located in the bin>release folder on Github.
The full src code can be found on this [Github](https://github.com/aszala/Local-HTML-file-browser).

First Click File>Open Directory

[image]

You should be presented with a window like this.
If the window appears to be cut off at the bottom, you may have to move the window up or resize it to be smaller.

[image]

Navigate to the folder in which all your HTML files are stored. And then click "Ok".
Since you are loading over 1000 HTML files this may take a little while to load. Please allow for a couple of minutes while all the files are being loaded.

Once it is done all your files should appear on the panel to the left side.

[image]

While the scroll bar appears to be going sideways, I assure you that the down arrow will still work.

Clicking on a file on the left panel will load it on the right side for your viewing. Pressing up arrow or down arrow will automatically load the next file. If you ever wish to view the code then you can see it by pressing the "Toggle Code / Browser" button at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows then simply enable the Preview Pane by selecting the tab View > Preview Pane or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. No need for any 3<sup>rd</sup> party software

[image: Preview Pane]

You may want to [make the pane wider](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=63) to fit the web page better. I often use this to preview a large number of docx/xlsx/pptx/pdf... files

On Vista and Windows 7 the menu position is different

[image: Preview Pane on Windows 7]